# php not finding installed libraries gd2 and xmlrpc

Tags: php

I am trying to install composer and i have the following erros:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\gd2 (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\gd2 (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlrpc' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\xmlrpc (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xmlrpc.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Regarding gd2.dll i do have the library installed in my ext folder.

And i have both extensions in my php.ini

```
extension=gd
extension=gd2
```

Same for xmlrpc.

I´ve tried commenting gd and leaving gd2 only but the error persists.

My extension_dir is the following:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

How can i solve these issues? The error also comes out if i run php -v

Comment: Shouldn't you use `extension=gd2.dll` if the file is called `gd2.dll`?

Answer (score -1):

Since the XML-RPC extension is not well maintained, better use a pure PHP implementation like this polyfill: github.com/gggeek/polyfill-xmlrpc

Comment: This won't resolve the error for loading the gd2 module